# ActiveSupport encode_big_decimal_as_string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to use the `ActiveSupport` option `encode_big_decimal_as_string` on one of my models. Should I put it in the model? Do I call this method on a model instance? Do I place this somewhere in config? What is an `ActiveSupport` option and how could I use it?

Answer (score 7):

Neither of these answers worked for me in Rails 4.0.  Here is what works in Rails 4.0:

```
ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding.encode_big_decimal_as_string = false
```

Add that line to your application config, like so:

```
# config/application.rb

...
module AppName
  class Application < Rails::Application
    ...
    ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding.encode_big_decimal_as_string = false
    ...
  end
end
```

As @tyler-nguyen said, this is being [deprecated](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html) in Rails 4.1, and extracted into this gem: [ActiveSupport JSON Encoder](https://github.com/rails/activesupport-json_encoder).  Refer to the gem documentation for configuration in 4.1.

Comment: For Rails 4.1, add `gem 'activesupport-json_encoder'` to your Gemfile in addition to the `config/application.rb` modification above.

Comment: Sadly, `activesupport-json_encoder` has been fully deprecated for Rails 5+ (see the `gemspec` at the link above).

Answer (score 3):

In Rails 4.0, you can set it in your `application.rb` as following:

```
config.active_support.encode_big_decimal_as_string = false
```

From Rails 4.1, the `ActiveSupport.encode_big_decimal_as_string` option is deprecated. The feature has been extracted to the [activesupport-json_encoder](https://github.com/rails/activesupport-json_encoder) gem.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that you do it in the `environment.rb` file.

This is what should work. I don't have a way to test it right now.

```
Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
  config.active_support.json.encode_big_decimal_as_string = true
end
```

Comment: got an error when starting the server: uninitialized constant Rails::Initializer (NameError)